# Eclipse (Aptana) Typing Lag

Tags: eclipse, aptana, lag

I've been using Aptana for some time now, and as of recent I've been dealing with files that are really, really big (500+ lines of code, which is huge for me, being a novice developer). Whenever I deal with smaller files, I get that weird sensation that I'm "in front of" what's typing, but now I'm quite sure of it--there is a significant lag between when I type something and when I see the text appear on screen. I don't have this issue with Dreamweaver CS3, so I know my computer has the capability to edit these files without this happening, but Eclipse still lags.

I also don't see when something is being deleted if I hold down backspace, I see the first few characters get deleted, but then everything "hangs." Once I release the backspace key, the characters that would've been shown deleting instantly vanish all at once. The same thing happens with the forward delete key.

I'm beginning to think this is an issue with Java, since I have the same feeling that everything is slightly "behind me" when I'm using -any- Java application.

The computer is an intel Pentium 4 3.2 GHz Prescott, with 2GB's of DDR400 RAM and a Radeon HD3650 graphics card.

If anyone knows how to fix this lagging issue, I'm all ears (eyes?); if anyone can recommend a different IDE with capabilities similar to Aptana (I do Python, HTML, CSS and JS; I use Git for SCM), I'd be glad to give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aptana is a great software, but you're facing one of it's disadvantages: it's a memory hog.

I'm using Aptana in a 4gb machine, but I remember having the same lags using the same configuration in your example.

If you can't live without Aptana (and Eclipe plugins), I suggest you to buy more RAM and use a HD that's at least 7200 RPM. I'm running in a Vista Machine and it works flawlessly.

If you can live without Aptana, check other Python IDE's in "[What IDE to Use for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)" question right here in SO.

My 2 cents: I've used PyScripter for Python, and it's great. PyScripter with notepad++ is a good and fast choice.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

I'm running a brand new iMac i5 with 8GB RAM and an SSD and Eclipse is slow as hell. I don't know if upgrading your machine is really the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

In my case Aptana also was very slow while typing, and it helped to choose 
Eclipse > Help > Aptana Troubleshooting > Clear Aptana Log File ...

Comment: This helped me as well with Eclipse Kepler + Aptana 3.4.2.

Comment: Cheers, now I finally know what was causing this!

Answer (score 2):

I bet You have default amount of memory assigned to Eclipse in eclipse.ini file - go there and increase those values 2-3 times. Eclipse will work much faster.

Comment: In my case (OSX Mountain Lion on a brand new 15" MBP w/ 16GB memory) I needed to edit the Aptana Studio INI file, per instructions I found here: http://www.techskater.com/web-stuff/giving-more-memory-to-aptana/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the most recent version of Aptana (3.1.3.201205292243) and had this exact same problem.  Increasing the memory allotments did nothing for me.  The problem goes away, however, if I turn off the Word Wrap option in the editor.

This is found in:

```
 Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Editors->Enable Word Wrap
```

I know, it's a stupid fix, but it works.  :)

Luck, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exactly same problem. Eclipse with Aptana Studio installed is really slow and not usuable for developing. Increasing the memory did not help at all. But what actually help (at least as far as I can tell until now), was to delete the Aptana log files as migg proposed.

(Eclipse Juno, Aptana Studio 3, OS X 10.8.2, Macbook Pro Retina)